# C# WPF DataGrid populating DataGrid problem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to make a 7-day rolling average weight calculator in WPF DataGrid. So basically the sum of your weight over the week divided by 7 = your 7-day average weight. So the user puts in their weight in the `ObservableCollectionsList` called `gridListValues` which is then added to the `DataGrid`. and after 7 days they get their 7day averageWeight in another column in the DataGrid.

The problem is that when I have input the weight seven times in the DataGrid I get this outcome:
`((6 * weight) / 7)`. But the actual outcome should be `((7 * weight) / 7)`. and I think it's because I'm calling the method that does the calculation at the same time as I'm instancing the object and adding it to the list? Not quite sure how I should solve this though. Here's the code:

```
private void AddWeightToGridButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WeightGridValues averageWeight = new WeightGridValues();

    if (gridListValues.Count <= 5)
        gridListValues.Add(new WeightGridValues { Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text, Date = Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid) });

    else if (gridListValues.Count >= 6)
    {
        gridListValues.Add(new WeightGridValues { Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text, Date = Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid), SevenDayWeightAverage = SevenDayAverageCalc(averageWeight) });
    }
}

private string SevenDayAverageCalc(WeightGridValues averageWeight)
{
    decimal sevenDayCalc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridListValues.Count; i++)
    {
        sevenDayCalc += Convert.ToDecimal(gridListValues[i].Weight);
        Convert.ToDecimal(gridListValues[i].SevenDayWeightAverage);
    }
    sevenDayCalc = sevenDayCalc / 7;
    
    return averageWeight.SevenDayWeightAverage = Convert.ToString(sevenDayCalc);           
}

public class WeightGridValues
{
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string SevenDayWeightAverage { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="WeightDataGrid" Margin="440,194,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Header=" Date " Binding="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Weight " Binding="{Binding Weight}" Width="80"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" 7-Day average " Binding="{Binding SevenDayWeightAverage}" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty `WeightGridValues` to `gridListValues`, and then set its individual elements.

```
gridListValues.Add(new WeightGridValues());
gridListValues[gridListValues.Count-1].Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text;
gridListValues[gridListValues.Count-1].Date= Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid);
gridListValues[gridListValues.Count-1].SevenDayWeightAverage = SevenDayAverageCalc(averageWeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an argument for the method `SevenDayAverageCalc`, there is a way to receive and process newly entered weight together.

```cs
private void AddWeightToGridButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WeightGridValues averageWeight = new WeightGridValues();

    if (gridListValues.Count <= 5)
    {
        gridListValues.Add(new WeightGridValues { 
            Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text, 
            Date = Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid) });
    }
    else if (gridListValues.Count >= 6)
    {
        gridListValues.Add(new WeightGridValues { 
            Weight = AddWeightToGrid.Text, 
            Date = Convert.ToString(AddDateToGrid), 
            SevenDayWeightAverage = SevenDayAverageCalc(averageWeight, AddWeightToGrid.Text) });
    }
}
```

And it is better to use a **`while`** statement rather than a `for` statement in `SevenDayAverageCalc` method, because **'7-day average'** must be calculated for each new row added.

```cs
private string SevenDayAverageCalc(WeightGridValues averageWeight, string newWeight)
{
    decimal sevenDayCalc = 0;
    int cnt = 1;
    int currentRow;

    while (cnt <= 6)
    {
        currentRow = gridListValues.Count - cnt;

        sevenDayCalc += Convert.ToDecimal(gridListValues[currentRow].Weight);
        Convert.ToDecimal(gridListValues[currentRow].SevenDayWeightAverage);
        cnt++;
    }

    sevenDayCalc = (sevenDayCalc + Convert.ToDecimal(newWeight)) / 7;

    return averageWeight.SevenDayWeightAverage = Convert.ToString(sevenDayCalc);
}
```

You can add up the existing six rows of data first in `while` statement, then add `newWeight` and divide it by 7.

#### Result

[image]